# Filter for Data based on Input of Column Header - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have data that consists of open ended notes/comments based on questions that are asked in a survey. Each column is a different question, with the column header being the question that was asked.

In a separate tab, I want to create a drop down where someone selects one of the questions asked, and the responses to that question will automatically filter.

Is there a way to set up a formula to pull the data in a column if the header of that column matches the drop down selected?

Comment: Welcome. Do read [ask] and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output